# How to set a parameter (width) in jQuery Slider plugin

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-slider

I am using this [jQuery Slider plugin](http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/) , i have to set a width like setting from,to in this plugin i was totally stuck in this one please help me to overcome this issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slider take the width of parent node.
So place the input in a container with desired width

```
<div class="span8">
     <input id="SliderSingle" type="slider" name="price" value="20" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.span8 {
      width:500px;
}
```

**EDIT**
If you want customize [the source](https://github.com/egorkhmelev/jslider/blob/master/js/jquery.slider.js) you should add at line 154

```
settings: {
  from: 1,
  to: 10,
  step: 1,
  smooth: true,
  limits: true,
  round: 0,
  format: { format: "#,##0.##" },
  value: "5;7",
  width: '100%', // add this line
  dimension: ""
},
```

and in line 237

```
this.domNode.css('width', this.OPTIONS.settings.width);
this.inputNode.after( this.domNode );
```

(untested)

Comment: yes i do the same if we are adding more slider in one page we should set width either in html/css can we do that one its library because i am trying to customize that slider if can you please tell me to add additional parameter to this plugin

Comment: do you want modify the source of plugin?

Comment: thats really awesome its working...Also i ahave a question if i am sliding towards right it stuck in the point when two pointer coincide any possible way to move right pointer to right side by keeping left one in same point

Answer (score 0):

You should set the css of `jslider` class to the wanted width, that's what I did when i used the same plugin.

Comment: yes i do the same if we are adding more slider in one page we should set width either in html/css can we do that one its library because i am trying to customize that slider if can you please tell me to add additional parameter to this plugin

Comment: I don't know how the plugin works and I don't think you can do it using any parameter of this, but I have several sliders in different widths because each is in another div: `.bigger .jslider{ width: 500px;} .smaller .jslider{ width:40px;}`